# Apache SkyWalking Infrastructure Monitoring

Tags: windows, monitoring, apm, skywalking

How to monitor Windows OS using Apache skywalking?
This feature is not available but what all changes in code helps to monitor windows?
please share vm.yaml file required for windows

Answer (score 1):

you could submit an issue(feature request) asking for this support.
Maybe some contributors have the interest to add this as a new feature.

Comment: An feature request had been submitted https://github.com/apache/skywalking/issues/10242

Comment: A contributor from the community just picked this, let's see whether we have a chance to support this in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows monitoring feature has been accepted by the upstream.
The doc is https://skywalking.apache.org/docs/main/next/en/setup/backend/backend-win-monitoring/

The earliest release including this feature should be 9.4.0